# Auto Convert Json String to C# Object

Tags: c#

I have this string below with '\t', '\r' and '\n' which I need to convert to a valid Json format with a loop so that I can Deserializeto an object without listing the object properties.

"Title\tFirstName\tLastName\tAge\r\nMr\tBla bla\tBla bla\t25\r\nMiss\tBla bla\tBla bla\t35\r\n"

Comment: Looks like a 'Do it for me' question... Have a go at it and come back with some code!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to solve your problem.

- First of all you need to split by `\r\n` - this will give you individual rows with data
- You can loop through these rows and split each of them by `\t` symbol - this will give you array of properties
- After you have all the "ingredients" - you can build your objects: using dynamic objects `new { firstName = arrayData[0], lastName = arrayData[1], ..}`, or you can create a new class with all the required properties
- Last step will be serialize collection of your objects into json - I would recommend `Json.NET` library for this purpose: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I'm trying to avoid listing the object properties like you mentioned, instead I just want to Deserialize with JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(textareaJsonStr)